# Concrete Syntax Matching in Rascal

Tags: rascal

If I have:

```
import demo::lang::Exp::Concrete::WithLayout::Syntax;
if ((Exp)`<IntegerLiteral e> + <IntegerLiteral e>` := (Exp)`5 + 6`) { 
    println(e);
}
```

This prints `6`. Is this a possible bug or a design decision, e.g. because of performance considerations? It should of course not print anything, since `e` cannot be matched to both `5` and `6`. This is, however, in contrast to matching with ADTs, where this *is* caught, i.e.:

```
data ExpNum = numb(int n) | add(ExpNum e1, ExpNum e2);
if (add(numb(x), numb(x)) := add(numb(5), numb(6))) { println(x); }
```

Will not print a number, while it does print a number when using `numb(5)` instead of `numb(6)`.

Ps. I ran the example both from Rascal source using Eclipse Plug-in Development (using a forked version merged with the latest version of Rascal), as well as on two machines using the official Eclipse plugin. The plugin, however, returned the following on both machines:

```
|stdin:///|(4,46,<1,4>,<1,50>): Java compilation failed due to with classpath [/home/wouter/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar]: package org.eclipse.imp.pdb.facts.type does not exist
```

The reason why I am asking is because, somewhat similarly, `ConcreteListVariablePattern` automatically throws a `RedeclaredVariable`-exception without checking if the match result's value is equivalent to the variable in the environment, in contrast to e.g. `QualifiedNamePattern` which checks if the result is equivalent to the value in the environment in case of a readily declared variable.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide examples for the other cases that you mention?

Comment: The other case was about having e.g. `\`{Param ","}* paramDups {Param ","} paramDups\`` in a syntax. This will assumably either throw an exception or behave erroneous like the example above (I am in the process of fixing my forked Rascal version, so I am not 100% sure). What I am curious about, however, is why variable reuse is not supported for variables in concrete patterns, while it is supported for variables in non-concrete patterns (e.g. the `numb(x), numb(x)`-example), as you state in your answer that it is supposed to throw a `RedeclaredVariable`-exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a bug: the variable `e` is declared twice (without warning), the match succeeds and the binding to second `e` is printed.
Expected behavior would be that a `RedeclaredVariable` exception is thrown.

A work around is as follows:

```
if ((Exp)`<IntegerLiteral e1> + <IntegerLiteral e2>` := (Exp)`5 + 6` && e1 == e2) { 
    println(e1);
}
```